# Как организовать структуру данных платёжных систем

Tags: django

Здравствуйте.

Возник вопрос, как лучше организовать структуру данных.

Предполагается что есть модель `PaymentMethod`, в которой хранятся способы оплаты, к примеру, пластиковая карта, WebMoney, Яндекс Деньги и т.д.

Предположительно, должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
class PaymentMethod(Base):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Способ оплаты"
        verbose_name_plural = "Способы оплаты"
```

Предположительно, в виде "сквозной модели", нужно хранить сами типы оплаты:

```
class PaymentType(Base):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Тип оплаты"
        verbose_name_plural = "Типы оплаты"
```

Ну а дальше, я не совсем понимаю как организовать.

Возьмём тот вариант, когда для каждого типа оплаты, имеется отдельная модель,
если следовать примеру, то Card, WebMoney, YandexMoney

И тогда каждая эта модель должна ссылаться на PaymentType внешним ключом, 
что-то типа:

```
class Card(Base):
    CARD_CHOICES = (
    ('VISA', _('Visa')),
    ('MasterCard', _('MasterCard')),
    )
    BANK_CHOICES = (
    ('AlphaBank', _('AlphaBank')),
    ('SberBank', _('SberBank')),
    )
    card_choices = models.CharField(choices=CARD_CHOICES, max_length=255)
    bank_choices = models.CharField(choices=BANK_CHOICES, max_length=255)
    payment_types = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(card_choices, bank_choices)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Пластиковвая карта"
        verbose_name_plural = "Пластиковвые карты"
```

Такая структура кажется правильной. По крайней мере на первый взгляд.

Но в таком случае не понятно, как быть с формой оплаты, когда нужно предоставить `PaymentMethod`, где за выбором `payment_type`, нужно сделать выборку возможных вариантов ( карточек, кошельков и т.д. ).
Ведь на PaymentType ссылаются разные модели. Как понять, по какой модели делать выборку, исходя из выбранного payment_type ?

Или вообще это лучше делать как-то иначе ?

Какие есть идеи, как это можно грамотно реализовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал следующим образом:

Оставил одну модель, назвав её `Payment`
Понял, что правильнее будет использовать `GenericForeignKey` и `limit`, для ограничения `content_type`, с которыми может связываться данная модель (в моём случае с моделью`Card`).

Так же, сделал модель Payment абстрактной, хотя можно и сослаться на сам платёж (какую-нибудь модель, вроде `Invoice`), если только Payment будет использоваться в связке с этой моделью.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    limit = models.Q(app_label='myapp', model='card')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        limit_choices_to=limit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Затем, для удобного автокомплита, и поиска по связанным `content_type` решил использовать [django_autocomplete_light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html).

views.py

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from queryset_sequence import QuerySetSequence

class PaymentAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetSequenceView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        cards = Card.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            cards = cards.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        qs = QuerySetSequence(cards)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        qs = self.mixup_querysets(qs)

        return qs
```

Здесь удобно менять логику поиска.

forms.py

```
class InvoiceForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    content_object = dal_queryset_sequence.fields.QuerySetSequenceModelField(
        queryset=autocomplete.QuerySetSequence(
            Card.objects.all(),
        ),
        required=False,
        widget=dal_select2_queryset_sequence.widgets.QuerySetSequenceSelect2('crm:payment-method-autocomplete'),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^payment-method-autocomplete/$',
        view=views.PaymentAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='payment-method-autocomplete',
    ),
]
```

Немного не так, как хотел изначально, и не без хаков, но работает так, как нужно.

Можно добавлять сколько угодно способов оплаты, отдельно охранить кошельки, карточки, и при этом не придётся сильно перестраивать структуру БД.